# openlayers-3 in node.js app?

Tags: node.js, openlayers-3

I'm interested in using ol3 in a node.js app (e.g. the ol.format APIs for reading GeoJSON). Is that a supported use case?

I ask because it doesn't appear to work by just running `npm install openlayers` and then requiring it. `var ol3 = require('openlayers')` fails on code that's looking for the `geolocation` property of the `window.navigation` object since the window.navigation doesn't exist in a node.js environment

TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'geolocation' in undefined
    at /home/me/src/ol3/node_modules/openlayers/dist/ol.js:144:823
    at OPENLAYERS (/home/me/src/ol3/node_modules/openlayers/dist/ol.js:9:22)
    at Object. (/home/me/src/ol3/node_modules/openlayers/dist/ol.js:13:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)

Comment: Can you elaborate? I suppose you have reasons to try this way.
Why do you need to use ol3 in a node.js app? It's not made firstly for server side. It's only to create/manipulate GeoJSON? If yes, I don't see the point to use OpenLayers 3 only for this. You can use other JS libraries.

Comment: I'd be happy to use another JS library on the server. I'm not very experienced in this area, so I'd be happy to be shown another way. What JS libraries do you recommend? I looked at gdal and its nodejs bindings (node-gdal), but it seems to be designed to read data from files, rather than from memory (e.g. the body of an HTTP request).

Comment: Can you reformulate your question so I can made an answer? In fact, your question seems to be related to GeoJSON manipulation from Node. Your OpenLayers 3 issue is only a "border effect".

Comment: Sure, but I would still be great to get an answer to this question. Is openlayers3 designed to only be used in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use OpenLayers 3 in purely Node context (but it's possible with Browserify/WebPack for client side use)

You can always stub `window` and other objects in Node but stub is for tests...
It's also possible to run OpenLayers 3 with PhantomJS (headless browser).

I'm not aware OpenLayers was designed for other uses than browser.

To get more insight, you should post your question on the [OpenLayers 3 dev list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ol3-dev) to confirm.

Do not duplicate exactly your StackOverflow question! You'd better ask something like "Is openlayers3 designed to only be used in the browser?" as the OpenLayers dev list is really for dev question and not about classic library usage/simple assistance nowadays.