# How to draw vector icons on node.js for openlayers' layer?

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api-3, draw, openlayers-3

I would like to draw 100-200k features/icons/markers to be used with openlayers v3.

Based on readings, the approach would be either to dp clustering, or let the server handle the drawings, in other words, use layer for that. This applies for google maps api.

So, i plan to use node.js (or php) for this task, but did not manage to find a proper module for node.js to do this.

Please recommend a module for this.

Or at least, how can i draw a png on node.

Specifically, I would like to create a layer where a request to my server, e.g: map.my.com/x/y/z.png would draw the markers on server (or predrawn), and not draw them on client side.

Comment: You should read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183186/openlayers-3-in-node-js-app) and [THIS](http://denelius.com/ol3-node-postgis/)

Comment: Thanks @MikelisBaltruks .. Thats a good read. But i guess i should have explained a bit further. I would like to create a layer where a request to my server, e.g: map.my.com/x/y/z.png would draw the markers on server (or predrawn), and not draw them on client side.I'm assuming thats what the artcile you pointed out is referring to.